# Reality Composer default Anchor

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit, reality-composer

When you create any scene with Reality Composer, you have to choose first what type of anchor "floor, wall, face, object" this mean when you load the scene it automatically places it self to the specified anchor.

[image]

My question is, Is there is any way to set it manually from code so that I would for example do a hit test and then anchor it to a specific point manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation has no reference to being able to change the default Anchor at runtime but from your description it sounds like you could try `Select Object Anchoring to Place a Scene Near Detected Objects` as described here:
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/creating_3d_content_with_reality_composer/selecting_an_anchor_for_a_reality_composer_scene

Comment: Nice. At least they say its possible 

Comment: Ill try it out and inform you

Answer (score 1):

> You can easily apply other type of anchor (when implementing hit-testing or ray-casting) using the following code (default anchor in Reality Composer is `.horizontal`):

```
import ARKit
import RealityKit

@IBAction func onTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let estimatedPlane: ARRaycastQuery.Target = .estimatedPlane              
    let alignment: ARRaycastQuery.TargetAlignment = .vertical           
    let tapLocation: CGPoint = sender.location(in: arView)

    let result: [ARRaycastResult] = arView.raycast(from: tapLocation,
                                               allowing: estimatedPlane,
                                              alignment: alignment)

    guard let rayCast: ARRaycastResult = result.first
    else { return }

    let anchor = AnchorEntity(world: rayCast.worldTransform)
    anchor.addChild(myScene)
    arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
}
```

Or you can place anchors automatically (for example, like `ARFaceAnchor` for detected face):

```
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession,didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

        guard let faceAnchor = anchors.first as? ARFaceAnchor
        else { return }

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: faceAnchor)

        // RealityKit's Facial analog
        // AnchorEntity(.face).self

        anchor.addChild(glassModel)        
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

...or you can place `ARImageAnchor` the same way:

```
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {

         guard let imageAnchor = anchors.first as? ARImageAnchor,
               let _ = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name
         else { return }

        let anchor = AnchorEntity(anchor: imageAnchor)

        // RealityKit's image anchor analog
        // AnchorEntity(.image(group: "Group", name: "model")).self

        anchor.addChild(imageModel)        
        arView.scene.anchors.append(anchor)
    }
}
```

Comment: But this requires user tapping on screen. I was wondering if there is a way to do it just by loading the object.

Comment: @MostafaMohamedRaafat, I've updated my answer. If you want to place anchors automatically use methodology shown in two last examples.